# How do I access layers of an object with a string?

Tags: php, xml, object, xml-parsing

Here is what I am trying to do.

I read an XML file and need to access certain properties. The problem is that this XML file might have one of 4 configurations.

What I want to be able to do is something like:

```
if(condition1){
  $title='PropertyParent->Child';
}
elseif(condition2){
  $title='DifferentProperty->AnotherLayer->DifferentChild';
}

$myTitle = $xml->$title;
```

and have  it access the object structure in the string. Is there any way to do this? Should I use variable variables?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way to do this is to use your own function:

```
function return_nested($xml_file, $condition)
{
    $cond_arr = explode("->", $condition);
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->load($xml_file);
    foreach($cond_arr as $cond)
    {
        $document = $document->getElementsByTagName( $cond )->item(0); //process each condition
    }
    return $document; //return element
}
```